# SHA1 Fingerprint of generated APK does not match Fingerprint of Keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, sha1

When uploading a new apk to the play store after exporting an app from Android Studio, I was given this error message
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B03sJ.png

When I verified the SHA1 on the keystore it seems to match the necessary SHA1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgQf1.jpg

I then extracted the CERT.RSA file from the META-INF folder in the APK.

When running the following keytool command on the CERT.RSA (that was given to me by google developer console support) it equaled the invalid fingerprint (89:92...)

```
$ keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA
```

Why does the fingerprint differ from the keystore and the apk?

Comment: Try exporting again and double check you are using the right keystore.

Comment: I only have the one keystore, and I got the same result.

Comment: Is your build variant debug or release when you are exporting? I'm not sure that would cause this issue, but make sure it is release.

Comment: It is set to release.

Comment: Try running `jarsigner -verify -verbose:summary -certs [apk]` on both the current apk and an old one that was published. See if they return the same info. If not, you are signing with a different keystore.

Comment: This is the response I got from running the new app (top) and the old app (bottom).

http://i.imgur.com/aa1SJ6b.jpg

Comment: It looks like everything is right. Sorry I'm out of ideas...

Comment: @AustenBennett How do you extract CERT.RSA and META INF from APK. When I tried to run these command keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA it shows no file found. But in apk those files are exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a workaround for this issue by manually signing the apk. It seems to be an issue with android studio in correlation with my keystore.